# Is it safe to persist Vuex state on sessionStorage?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, session-storage

I'm working on a web app using Vue.js/Vuex and when the user refreshes the page the state is lost.

I'm trying to persist some states in `sessionStorage`, but I realized that a user can edit it and for example make a state `true` and turn it into `false`.

My question(s) are:

Can a user edit the `sessionStorage`?

Is it safe to store a state in a `sessionStorage`?

Can I persist the state in another way without adding another dependency on the project?

**--------------UPDATE-----------------**

For people with a similar problem I solved using [beforeEnter and beforeEach](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) so instead of trying to persist the state I go to a backend endpoint everytime the route changes (with beforeEach) and every page refresh (with beforeEnter).

Thanks to everyone for the helpful responses!

Comment: **Anything** on the client side can be edited. Request headers, cookies, sessionStorage, user agents, form fields, disabling client-side validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your concern is about saving credentials in the store to `sessionStorage`. Storing tokens should be fine as long as you have robust authentication/validation logic at the backend. Don't store password though.

Comment: Also, as long as the user's device is not within the reach of a person with bad intentions. They could practically steal the details off from `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Comment: Thats precisely what I needed to know. I was going to store more of a permission, but I'll see if I can move it to the back end

Comment: I personally do front and backend validation for better UX. There is no harm doing both.